# render() called but DOM not updated

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have a react component which returns a list of items which is coming from a connected redux store.

The store is asynchronously updated by a thunk which leads to a call of the render() function in the component. Based on console.log diagnostics I can see that the render returns an updated structure containing the new data but the DOM is not updated.

The list has a key item. I also tried without a key and with a random key but the behavior is the same.

How do I further diagnose this problem?

This is the stripped down code of the component:

```
class BigDeviceNavigationComponent extends PureComponent<BigDeviceNavigationComponentProps> {

  renderBigNaviReservationItem(currentReservation: Reservation, items: number) {
    console.log('renderBigNaviReservationItem')

    const itemkey: string = 'bignavigation' + items.toString() + '_' + currentReservation.reservationCode;
    console.log(itemkey)

    const retval =  (
      <a key={itemkey}
        className={classNames('item w-100' )}
        href={'#'}
        onClick={() => {}        }
      >{itemkey}
      </a>
    );
    console.log(retval)
    return retval
  }

  render() {
    console.log('bigdevice render')
    console.log(this.props)
    const { reservation, items, bookingLinks } = this.props;

    const reservationList = reservation.list.map((currentReservation: Reservation) => {
      return this.renderBigNaviReservationItem(currentReservation, items);
    })
    console.log(reservationList)
    const retval = (
      <Container fluid={true} style={{paddingBottom:'0.25rem'}}>
        <Row>
          <Col md={6} className="py-0">

            {reservation.list.length > 0 && (
              <OwlCarousel
                className="vertical-center owl-theme px-3 reservation-selection"
                items={items}
                loop={false}
                dots={false}
                margin={10}
                nav={true}
                navText={[
                  '<i class="ion-chevron-left icon-big" />',
                  '<i class="ion-chevron-right icon-big" />',
                ]}
              >
                {reservationList}
              </OwlCarousel>
            )}
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    );
    console.log(retval)
    debugger;
    return retval
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: ApplicationReduxState): ApplicationReduxState => ({
  reservation: state.reservation,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch): ReduxDispatch => ({
  dispatch,
});

export default compose(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
  ),
)(BigDeviceNavigationComponent);
```

including my console.log outputs where I can see that the render returns the additional element but it doesn't find it's way into the dom.

The initial render in the debugger contains 8 items in reservationList:
[image: first debugger hit at initial render]

The second render triggered by the redux update contains 9 items but does not update the dom
[image: second debugger hit after redux update]

Comment: Please, include code you have so far - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Have you tried https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi 
You can verify the props in your component using it.

Comment: When it stumbles over the debugger; first time {reservationList} contains 8 items which are the rendered into the dom. When it stumbles over the debugger second time after the redux update the {reservationList} contains 9 items, but the DOM isn't changed.

Comment: It seems to be somehow related to the OwlCarousel. If I replace it by an <ul> everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Someone had the problem before and suggested a solution:
https://hashnode.com/post/react-js-render-method-called-with-state-update-but-component-view-did-not-update-cjq7ohku100dm57s1yk6qvp56

Adding a key that changes to the OwlCarousel triggers a refresh.